# How to extend parent types in child class in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I want to extend a class from a third party lib that looks like this:

```
class Parent {
  constructor(options?: {
    foo: string,
    bar: number
  }) {
    //...some constructor logic
  }
}
```

Somewhere in my code

```
class Child extends Parent {
  constructor(options) {
    // options has any type here
  }
}
```

How can I get `Parent` constructor's options type and extend it?

Answer (score 1):

```
interface ParentOptions {
  foo: string;
  bar: number;
}

class Parent {
  constructor(options?: ParentOptions) {
    //...some constructor logic
  }
}

interface ChildOptions extends ParentOptions {
  baz: boolean;
}

class Child extends Parent {
  constructor(options: ChildOptions) {
    // options has any type here
  }
}
```

Comment: That could be the answer, but I don't have access to the Parent class because it is a third party lib. Parent options type is inlined and not exported